# SQL Server String or Binary data would be truncated varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have seen this question posted numerous times, but none seem to address my variant of the problem.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 150
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Is the error that I am getting while pulling data from XML variables.

The XML structure is (simplified) like the following:

```
<View>
    <view_config>
        <gl_type>Box</gl_type>
        <data_access>
            <access_as></access_as>
            <access_id></access_id>
            ...
        </data_access>
        <data>
            <dimension x="1" y="2" z="3" />
            <is_position_relative>false</is_position_relative>
        </data>
    </view_config>
    <view_config>
    ...
    </view_config>
</View>
```

Where in my data-set the only XML that gives an issue has 168  nodes. The error occurs 27 times and only while parsing that particular XML data with this code:

```
declare @graphics table(
    rowNum INT IDENTITY(0,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    graphicName VARCHAR(MAX),
    vcXML XML,
    numComponents int
)
declare @viewConfigs table(
    rowNum int identity(0,1)primary key clustered,
    graphicName varchar(max),
    viewIndex int,
    gl_type varchar(max),
    access_as varchar(10),
    ...
    dimX float, dimY float, dimZ float,
    posRelative varchar(max)
)

insert into @graphics(graphicName,vcXML)
(select graphic_name,viewcenter_config from ProjAuto_Graphics) order by graphic_name

declare @m int, @n int
declare @xml XML
set @m = 0
select @n = COUNT(*) from @graphics
while @m < @n
begin
    update @graphics
    set numComponents = (select max(vcXml.value('count(//view_config)','int'))
    from @graphics where rowNum = @m
    set @m = @m + 1
end
set @m = 0

select @xml = vcXML FROM @graphics where rowNum = @m

declare @graphicName varchar(30)
declare @glType varchar(30) --Increased these values while trying to debug.
declare @dimX float, @dimY float, @dimZ float
declare @rltv varchar(max)
--other variables needed to fill in the table

declare @data table(
    rowNum int identity(0,1)primary key clustered,
    dX float, dY float, dZ float,...,rltv varchar(max)
)--I had to make this table due to the nested structure of the XML

while @m < @n --This loops over each graphic in the table
begin
    select @xml = vcXML from @graphics where rowNum = @m
    INSERT INTO @data
    SELECT
        Tbl.Col.value('(dimension/@x)[1]','varchar(max)'),
        Tbl.Col.value('(dimension/@y)[1]','varchar(max)'),
        Tbl.Col.value('(dimension/@z)[1]','varchar(max)'),
        Tbl.Col.value('(is_position_relative)[1]','varchar(max)')
    FROM @xml.nodes('//data') Tbl(Col)

    declare @i int, @j int
    set @i = 0
    set @j = numComponents from @graphics where rowNum = @m
    while @i < @j
    begin
        --store values from @data into temp variables to make an insert statement
        select @dimX = dX from @data where rowNum = @i
        select @dimY = dY from @data where rowNum = @i
        select @dimZ = dZ from @data where rowNum = @i
    print @graphicName -- Debugging
        select @rltv = rltv from @data where rowNum = @i
        insert into @viewConfigs(graphicName,gl_type,...,rltv)
        values(@graphicName,@glType,...,@rltv)
        set @i = @i + 1
    end
    set @m = @m + 1
end
```

So I have gone through every variable that I use for that node and made sure they are all set as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, even the ones used in the xquery syntax. I have also tested a query to see if there are any values for `is_position_relative` other than `false` and there are not, in addition to manually inspecting the XML for the particular graphic that causes the error to occur.

Finally when I view the results in SQL Server, there are no `NULL` values in my table, let alone any non-`false` values.

What could still be causing this error, and what is the result of the error occurring (because it doesn't seem to mess up my results)?

Comment: “pulling data” how? From the SQL Server management console? Open Query/Options/Results/Maximum characters retrieved an ensure the UI is not truncating your displayed characters.

Comment: In my code posted, I query the XML variable of each graphic, set it to a temporary variable and then use XQuery statements on that temporary variable to parse out the individual nodes.

Comment: What is in Line 150?

Comment: `select @rltv = rltv from @data where rowNum = @i`